# Definition of an isotrivial family

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, definition

A definition that I've seen for an isotrivial family $\mathcal{X} \longrightarrow B$ (for schemes $\mathcal{X}, B$ over some scheme $S$) is one where $X_s \cong X_t$ for all $s, t \in U$ in some dense open subset $U \subset B$. What is exactly meant by $X_s \cong X_t$ when $s, t$ aren't closed points of $B$?

If $s, t$ are closed points of $B$, we can simply look at set-theoretic preimages and define an isomorphism over $S$ (e.g. $S = \text{Spec } k$ for some field $k$). In general, does this mean that there is some scheme $A$ defined over $S$ such that $A \times_S \text{Spec } k(s) \cong A \times_S \text{Spec } k(t)$ for all $s, t \in U$? As a general question about comparing fibers, how do we compare a fiber over the closed point with that of the generic point for the squaring map $\mathbb{A}_k^1 \setminus 0 \longrightarrow \mathbb{A}_k^1 \setminus 0$?

Comment: I suspect the comparison is only over the closed points. There is often a convention to mean closed points when the author says "point" unless otherwise specified

Comment: I agree with the first comment. Also notice that if we have a non-closed point, take the fiber, and take its closure, we get a "smaller" family which is also isotrivial. Obvious, but maybe helpful?

Comment: I understand. There's a point related to the last part of the question which seems a bit confusing. Given a morphism of schemes $\mathcal{X} \longrightarrow B$ such that $B$ is of finite presentation (or finite type), it seems like the subset of $s \in B$ where the fiber $X_s$ is finite dimensional or with a given number of geometrically irreducible components is constructible. Initially, this made it seem like having $|X_s| = n$ for all closed points $s \in B$ implies the same is true for all $s \in B$. However, this seems to be false for the squaring map. What exactly is going wrong here?